# How can I write (draw) notes or just drawings, with a 2d stroke but on the 3d viewport

Tags: modeling, sculpting, photorealism

How can I write (draw) notes or just drawings, with a 2d stroke but on the 3d viewport.[image]

Comment: Have a look into the grease pencil: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two tools to do what you want: the grease pencil and annotations.

The grease pencil can be rendered,

https://www.blender.org/features/grease-pencil/

annotations are just for reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-IJ7THnd2ZM

Comment: Thank you! I will go for the second option you gave!